# How to create a PHP function only visible within a file?

Tags: php

How to create a PHP function only visible within a file? Not visible to external file. In other word, something equivalent to static function in C

Comment: When you include files on PHP it is as if you are appending them together,  in C/C++ you are "importing" the variables/functions/classes.

Answer (score 11):

There is no way to actually make a function only visible within a file. But, you can do similar things.

For instance, create a lambda function, assign it to a variable, and unset it when your done:

```
$func = function(){ return "yay" };

$value = $func();

unset($func);
```

This is provided that your script is procedural.

You can also play around with namespaces.

---

Your best bet is to create a class, and make the method private

Comment: Closures/lambda functions (note these require at least php 5.3) are probably your only option, besides re-thinking your need hide the function from other files.  You probably don't actually need to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Create a class and make the method private.

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    private $bar = 'baz';

    public function doSomething()
    {
        return $this->bar = $this->doSomethingPrivate();
    }

    private function doSomethingPrivate()
    {
        return 'blah';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [namespace](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.namespaces.php), for apply your own visibility.

> In the PHP world, namespaces are designed to solve two problems that
>   authors of libraries and applications encounter when creating
>   re-usable code elements such as classes or functions:
>
> 1. Name collisions between code you create, and internal PHP classes/functions/constants or third-party classes/functions/constants.
> 2. Ability to alias (or shorten) Extra_Long_Names designed to alleviate the first problem, improving readability of source code.